# How to customize email notification template using HTML Codes in gravity form

Tags: html-email, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

How can I customize email notification template in gravity forms using HTML codes?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is a site where we help if you have a code that is broken or is not working. Questions like this get flagged. I suggest taking a [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about the type of questions that are accepted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.